# Ruby on Rails: Postgres, connect as different user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, devise

I have a Rails app that successfully talks to a Postgres database.  The app has full Postgres access rights and is successfully talking to the database.

I use Devise to authenticate my users.  I know this is independent of PG but I mention it to make what I want below somewhat clearer.

The app maintains a (Devise) table of users. The app has several users and I want to have each user have different access (roles?) to the database.

I want to create a sandbox where User can issue PG commands but has, for instance, only readonly access rights to the database.

How do I do this.  I've searched Google for several hours but I've come up with zilch.

Comment: I'm would like to suggest you to take a use cancancan gem merged with device here is a link for my suggestion https://github.com/mezbahalam/devise_cancan

Comment: I like cancancan but I find pundit to be even better!  Checkout the pundit gem for authorization.

Comment: I thank @widjajayd and (bkunsi01) for your suggestions.  Unfortunately I don't need an authorization system for Rails.  What I need to know is how to change authorization/access (roles?) for Postgres tables and databases for a Rails session.

Comment: I thank widjajayd and @bkunsi01 for your suggestions.  Unfortunately I don't need an authorization system for Rails.  What I need to know is how to change authorization/access (roles?) for Postgres tables and databases for a Rails session.